# Content search web part ( CSWP ) based on url / sitecollection - Cross site publishing - sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, cross-site, cross-site-publishing, content-search-web-part

I'm having 6-7 different sitecollection with different styling, menues, (managed) navigation ... using only (1) masterpage!

```
ex:
http://awesomewebpage.com (styling.css)
http://awesomewebpage.com/hr  <-- different styling / menu / navigation .. (hr.css)
http://awesomewebpage.com/people <- differnt styling / menu / navigation .. (people.css)
```

I want to add css and other type of queries in each sitecoll (URL), how can I manage this? 
Is there a way for content search web part to write out  "/hr/", "people" .. based on the url

I know I can find what sitecollection each "article" / page / site are located in. But the problem is when I'm doing cross site publishing I don't want to keep the original styling / menu / navigation .. but I want it to have the look of what sitecollection I'm currently in.

```
ex:
1. publishing a site on http://awesomewebpage.com/hr 
   (get the right styling /navigation / menu)   (hr.css)
2. then cross site publish the site to http://awesomewebpage.com/people .. 
   then I want the site to get the (people.css) instead of the originaly (hr.css).
```

This is just an example on styling and I know I can manage this by making by regex ....

But how can I mange this using content search web part? I need it to work with the content search web part to get the right navigation / menues.

Comment: AFAIK this is the default behavior. You can style results in each site collection that consumes the data. Can you elaborate further on your requirement? Are you in fact using the Cross Site Publishing feature, or just your custom made variant?

Comment: Trying to use cross site publishing. The problem is that when I (cross-site) publish the same site to another sitecollection it get the default/same branding. And not the branding on the actual site.